# htmlspecialchars except ampersand when starting another entity

Tags: php, html

I am using `htmlspecialchars` for printing non-HTML data from an administrative web form. The issue is HTML entities and unicode characters/symbols like ® which prints `&reg;` or ★ which prints as `&#9733;` due to the ampersand getting converted.

I know I could just replace all `&amp;` with `&` to get around this issue, but that isn't appropriate when just printing an ampersand character.

What is a good approach for converting special characters, except ampersands when preceding a symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a string that already is partially encoded. Encoding it again leads to the problem you describe.

To get around that, you could decode the string first and then encode it again:

```
$encoded_string = htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($partially_encoded_string));
```

**Edit:** If all characters need encoding, you can use `htmlentities()` instead:

```
$encoded_string = htmlentities(html_entity_decode($partially_encoded_string));
```

Comment: This will work, however, it leaves the actual unicode symbol in the source, and I'd prefer to leave the named HTML entity if possible

Comment: @steveo225 Then you should use `htmlentities()` instead of `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for unicode symbols like ★

Comment: @steveo225 Then you could give `mb_convert_encoding($utf8_string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')` a try...

Comment: That is the magic function that I was not aware of. Thank you